# Customize Enterprise Content Management (ECM)

Tags: 2010

In Exam 70-573 there is a topic:

Customize Enterprise Content Management (ECM)

This objective may include but is not limited to: creating a content type that inherit from appropriate parent, creating and implementing a custom publishing field control that is page mode aware, activating a master page programmatically including token usage

This objective does not include: page layouts, formatting

I'd like to know more about this topic, some linkgs might be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the content I found for this topic:

http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Exam%2070573%20Study%20Guide/DispForm.aspx?ID=13&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.beckybertram.com%2FLists%2FExam%252070573%2520Study%2520Guide%2FAllItems.aspx